# How to convert pixel linear index position to (x, y) coordinates?

Tags: grid, coordinates, formula, pixel

Hopefully after this question is answered, it will no longer be so difficult to search the answer to this question on this website.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript:

```js
// i == zeroed index of pixel
const x = i % width;
const y = Math.floor(i / width);
```